# Where is the implementation of syscall.Entersyscall?

Tags: go, system-calls

I am trying to trace down how syscalls work in Go, but I got stuck [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/gccgo.go#L29).

The code is invoking `syscall.Entersyscall`, but I cannot find the definition for the `Entersyscall` function in the `syscall` package anywhere in the source tree.

Is there some magic that renames this to something else?

More generally, how does one go about finding definitions for function names (in the Go source tree) that have no apparent definition in their advertised package?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find it in the stdlib because it contains just a wrapper function `syscall.Entersyscall()`. The proper implementation is in the same package but written in asm [golang.org/src/syscall/asm_linux_arm.s](https://golang.org/src/syscall/asm_linux_arm.s)

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused; what does Entersyscall get turned into?

Comment: `syscall.Entersyscall()` is just a definition of a function in the go file (without implementation). Implementation is done in a separate file in another language (C, ASM etc.). During compilation process both files compile into binary data and then link together into one executable file.

Comment: Is there some documentation of which names in Go correspond with which names in the implementation?